# Visual glitch on toolbar when dialog fragment is shown

Tags: android

Whenever a dialog fragment is opened above one of the activities in my app or it undergoes a screen size transition (ex. multi window resize), the toolbar undergoes an odd visual glitch.

I manually set the color of the toolbar via code, and this seems to be part of the problem:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Scout: Team " + scoutData.getTeamNumber()); //TODO match number, Qualification
   getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Qualification Match " + scoutData.getMatchNumber());

   int toolbarColor = ((ColorDrawable) findViewById(R.id.toolbar).getBackground()).getColor();

   int statusBarColor;
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       statusBarColor = getWindow().getStatusBarColor();
   } else {
       statusBarColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark);
   }

   TransitionUtils.toolbarAndStatusBarTransition(toolbarColor, statusBarColor,
           getResources().getColor(scoutData.getAllianceColor().getColorPrimary()),
           getResources().getColor(scoutData.getAllianceColor().getColorPrimaryDark()), this);
```

Method in TransitionUtils:

```
public static void toolbarAndStatusBarTransition(final int toolbarColor, final int statusBarColor, final int toolbarToColor, final int statusBarToColor, final AppCompatActivity activity) {
    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            // Use animation position to blend colors.
            float position = animation.getAnimatedFraction();

            // Apply blended color to the status bar.
            int blended = blendColors(statusBarColor, statusBarToColor, position);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(blended);
            }

            // Apply blended color to the ActionBar.
            blended = blendColors(toolbarColor, toolbarToColor, position);
            ColorDrawable background = new ColorDrawable(blended);
            activity.getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(background);

            if (activity instanceof ScoutingFlowActivity) { //we don't want a random null
                activity.findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout).setBackground(background);
                activity.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout).setBackground(background);
            }
        }
    });
    anim.setDuration(350).start();

    //if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { //tint in Overview
    //ActivityManager.TaskDescription tDesc = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(null, null, toolbarToColor);
    //activity.setTaskDescription(tDesc);
    //}
}
```

This is my activity layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="30dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="30dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is by far the weirdest glitch I've encountered. It doesn't actually harm anything but is immensely irritating.

Screenshot of glitch:
[image: Glitch]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @azizbekian Screenshot added to post.

Comment: Use Layout inspector to understand what's happening. Tools -> Android -> Layout Inspector.

Comment: @azizbekian The Layout inspector shows this visual bug even when it isn't present on my screen...

Comment: Interestingly, I've found that setting either the ```toolbar``` or the ```tabLayout``` to have a different background works fine, and it's only when I set both that this error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing

```
// Apply blended color to the ActionBar.
blended = blendColors(toolbarColor, toolbarToColor, position);
ColorDrawable background = new ColorDrawable(blended);
activity.getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(background);

if (activity instanceof ScoutingFlowActivity) { //we don't want a random null
    activity.findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout).setBackground(background);
    activity.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout).setBackground(background);
}
```

to

```
// Apply blended color to the ActionBar.
blended = blendColors(toolbarColor, toolbarToColor, position);
activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar).setBackgroundColor(blended);

if (activity.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout) != null) { //we don't want a random NPE
    activity.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout).setBackgroundColor(blended);
}
```

The change in the if statement is irrelevant- it's the use of `setBackgroundColor()` instead of `setBackground()` that appears to have solved the issue.